# Cancel procedure called by right mouse click event with right mouse click event

Tags: vb.net

The procedure below runs when I click the right button on my mouse. The procedure runs fine, it places a with border around my button.  What I want to accomplish is when the user clicks the right mouse again, the weight is set to 0 and the border to none.

Here is my procedure:

```
    Private Sub btnEmployeeDashboard_MouseDown(ByValsender As Object, ByVal myButton As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnEmployeeDashboard.MouseDown

    If myButton.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then

        btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.ColorIndex = 2
        btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.Weight = 4

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a value to toggle on. I assume your right click means something, so just set a variable and add and if statement to your event.

```
Dim ButtonClicked as boolean = false 

Private Sub btnEmployeeDashboard_MouseDown(ByValsender As Object, ByVal myButton As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnEmployeeDashboard.MouseDown

If myButton.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then

    If ButtonClicked then 

         btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.Weight = 0
         ButtonClicked = false
    else

         btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.ColorIndex = 2
         btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.Weight = 4
         ButtonClicked = true
    endif



End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer send me on the right path.  I was able to work it out using a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code modified. I used the toggle as set it as static. So as a boolean, it gave me what I was looking for.

```
    Private Sub btnEmployeeDashboard_MouseDown(ByValsender As Object, ByVal myButton As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnEmployeeDashboard.MouseDown

    Static Toggle As Boolean

    If myButton.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then

        If Toggle Then

            btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.Weight = 1

        Else

            btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.ColorIndex = 2
            btnEmployeeDashboard.Border.Weight = 4

        End If

    End If
    Toggle = Not Toggle

End Sub
```